# Proof of the triangle inequality for the rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I am trying ti prove that rk(A+B)≤rkA + rkB, where rkA means rank of matrix A, and A is mxn, as well as B.

By the fundamental theorem of linear algebra we know that rkA≤n and rkB≤n, so that we have rkA + rkB≤2n. On the other hand we know that rk(A+B)≤n, and I was trying to use that to arrive at a contradiction by assuming the opposite of what I want to prove, but I could not get any contradiction, could you help me point in the right direction?

Comment: the rank is the dimension of the image. Try to think about images

Comment: The $rk(A+B)=rk(A)+rk(B)-rk(A\cap B)$. So, $rk(A+B)+rk(A\cap B)=rk(A)+rk(B)$. So, $rk(A+B)+j=rk(A)+rk(B)$ for some $j\in \mathbb{W}$. Hence, $rk(A+B)\leq rk(A)+rk(B)$.